# Safely inject html string into <pre> tag keeping syntax highlighting intact

Tags: javascript, html

I have `string` containing `json` data built dynamically with some `html` inserted for syntax highlighting.

```
console.log(highlightedJson);
{
    <span class="key">"time":</span> <span class="string">"11:09:09 PM"</span>,
    <span class="key">"milliseconds_since_epoch":</span> <span class="number">1406070549038</span>,
    <span class="key">"date":</span> <span class="string">"07-22-2014"</span>
}
```

Styling to be applied to classes:

```
pre {
    outline: 1px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 5px; 
    margin: 5px; 
    white-space: pre-wrap;       
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    
    word-wrap: break-word;       
}
.string { color: green; }
.number { color: darkorange; }
.boolean { color: blue; }
.null { color: magenta; }
.key { color: red; }
```

Trying to inject this as `html` into a `<pre>` dom element ..

```
var pre = document.createElement('pre');

// also tried this, but again, syntax highlighting is not rendered
//pre.appendChild(highlightedJson));

pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(highlightedJson))
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(pre);
```

When this code runs, the string is appended to `<pre>`, but syntax highlighting is not showing.

- I know using `pre.innerHTML = highlightedJson;` gets the result I'm after but this html injection method is discouraged in firefox addons.
- Project is not using `jquery`

Can anyone suggest an approach?

Comment: Why are you calling `appendChild` with a string?  Have you already converted `highlightedJson` to a DOM fragment?  What do you mean by *safely inject*?  Are you worried about XSS because the JSON might come from an untrusted source?

Comment: No, its not converted to a DOM fragment it's a `string`. I tried this also, but syntax highlighting is not rendered: `pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(highlightedJson))`. To quote an addon reviewer in reference to `innerHTML`, "Aside from being inefficient, this is a major security risk"

Comment: Appending the text node seems like the right approach - why the highlighting would fail to apply to the rendered text is a different question. What are you using for syntax highlighting?

Comment: createTextNode isn't supposed to parse html I think.

Comment: CSS isn't able to parse through text and apply styling to substrings; the only way to keep syntax highlighting would be to create DOM elements, which is what happens when you set `innerHTML`. You could create the individual nodes yourself rather than just setting `innerHTML`. If you're going to do that it might be easier to send the JSON as objects like `[{"key":"time","type":"number","value":1406070549038},...]` for example. That way you don't need to parse the HTML from a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var htmlStr = '<div><span style="color:#FF0;">h</span>ello</div>';
var range = document.createRange();
var anyElement = document.body;
range.selectNode(anyElement);
var docFrag = range.createContextualFragment(htmlStr);
document.body.appendChild(docFrag);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KD2RR/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this which is used for innerHTML problems with IE. It might also be useful for this situation.

```
function stringToHTML(str){
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;
    while(div.firstChild){
        frag.appendChild(div.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}

var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.appendChild(stringToHTML(highlightedJson));
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(pre);
```

This is my suggestion because of your requirement of a string being converted to render-able html. Because you can't just have html from a string innerHTML is the best bet, but because of security implications I see this as an alternative. If you need to you can run checks in the while loop to exclude tags you don't want, or just white list your span tags.

If you really need the security try [html parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM) then. Google about this stuff.

Comment: this still uses `.innerHTML` which i think ff addon reviewers will not like

Comment: Then use html parser.